about setting up firebase to my visual studio flutter app
enter image description here
How can resolve this issue to run my flutter app android authentication?
Log in and test the Firebase CLI
After installing the CLI, you must authenticate. Then you can confirm authentication by listing your Firebase projects.

Log into Firebase using your Google account by running the following command:


firebase login,

i have tried to type the firebase login on that console but got those errors. i would like to know how to resolve it and how i can install the firebase to run my project in visual studios  authentication

Please don't post screenshots or photos of your error messages, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
